# Get x,y from 2d list and pass on

Tags: python, list, 2d

I'm trying to take a 2d list of locations that incl lat/ longs and get only the coordinates from the list (in column 3 and 4) to send to another function so that distances can be calculated... but I'm totally stumped.
What I have is...

EDITED from OP to show where I'm at...
    x1 = -18.00   #These values don't change
    y1 = 118.00
    x2 = float(origList[3])
    y2 = float(origList[4])
    n = len(origList)
    appList  = []

```
for i in range (n-1):
    appList.append(findDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    print appList
```

But now I get...File "F:\Storage\t_2\coord_find.py", line 27, in main,x2=math.fabs(origList[3])
TypeError: a float is required

So the problem is in the conversion to float???

Then all I have so far for the findDistance function (I only just started it and just want to test if arguments are being passed correctly)...
    def findDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        cosX = math.fabs(y1 - y2)
        a = 90 - x2
        b = 90 - x1

---

Here's my updated code that is giving me this...

delx = math.fabs(y1 - y2)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list'

I'm posting it up because I obviously didn't give a clear enough explanation and have made some changes since. AS you can see, I want to get the x2,y2 from cols 3,4.
Tried x2=float(origList[3]), y2=float(origList[4]) but that doesn't work either- I get "float()argument must be a string or a number".
Do I need to split the list somehow before trying to extract the values as floats??

```
import csv
import math

def fZone():
    origList = [['200','12_7','Cons_pl','-20.10','120.10','C_10_T2'],['....'...]]
    # origList has 30+ lines like this
    x1 = -20.68     # Fixed point
    x2 = 117.19     # Fixed point
    n = len(origList)   # list length
    appList = []    # to hold returned 

    for i in range (n):
        x2= origList[3] # I wanna get the '-20.10' col each iteration
        y2= origList[4] # I wanna get the '120.10' col each iteration
        appList.append(findDist(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        print appList

def findDist(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    delx = math.fabs(y1 - y2)
        a = 90 - x2
        b = 90 - x1  # formula is not finished
```

Comment: What is the exact traceback? How is `findDistance` defined? What is `origList`?

Comment: origList is the original 2d list with x and y and some other fields. x is in col 3 and y is col 4. I loop through each pair of x,y sending them to the findDistance function and get the distance returned

Answer (score 0):

Your `origList[0:]` evaluates to `origList`. Try `origList[0]`.

`range(0,n-1)` only goes up to n-2, and you have no need to specify the starting value of 0 since that's the default anyway. Use `range(n)`.

You say the coordinates are in columns 3 and 4. It looks like you're somewhat new to indexing in a programming language, so I hope I don't offend with a gratuitous reminder that you might be looking for list elements 2 and 3, if you mean that these are the 3rd and 4th columns.

Also, the `print` should be outside the loop.

Comment: Given how the loop is written I'd say its `len(orglist)`, not `len(orglist[0])`.

Comment: I added the whole traceback then realised in the calculation I have (y1-y2) but I brought them in as origList[i][3] etc. I guess I need to place the variables x2, y2 under the other ones and make them =origList[3] and =origList[4], or something like that??        BTW, I thought [0:] would skip the first line which is the header

Comment: If it is really a 2d list, `len(latList)` will give the number of records, while len(orgList[0]) will give the length of each record. So it depends whether lat/lon are in record 3/4 or column 3/4. Given OP, I agree with 6502.

Comment: Sorry, x,y are columns 4,5 so the index is as stated (3,4). I made the other changes as suggested...len(origList), range(n), etc but still get the traceback error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your list is containing pairs of strings, not of numbers.

In Python this conversion is never automatic so you will probably have to change the code to:

```
findDistance(x1, y1, float(origList[i][3]), float(origList[i][4]))
```

An error like

```
lat2= float(stnList[3])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

clearly says what was passed to float was neither a number nor a string.

Just add a `print repr(stnList[3])` right before the offending statement and check out what was passed instead.

You can also the python debugger to find what the problem is, check for example this short video of a [pdb session example](http://youtu.be/IS0OtNq3VHo)

Comment: OK the list does have strings so I changed the call to findDistance(x1,x2,y1,y2), and added the y1, y2 variables below x1, x2 so they are y1=float(origList[3]), y2=float(origList[4]) but now get...  " lat2= float(stnList[3])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number"

Comment: I exhausted daily amount of the magic power of reading source code without seeing it that I'm allowed to use on a Saturday morning. I will not tell what is the error in public unless you show everyone the source code.

Comment: Bugger, because its my first post I gotta wait to post the updated code

Comment: Seeing a though I cant post atm, all I have for the function the coords are passed to is...                                       def findDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        cosX = math.fabs(y1 - y2)
        a = 90 - x2
        b = 90 - x1